# wcf service creating proxy by using svcutil.exe in command prompt?

Tags: wcf

when i am trying to generate proxy manually using comand prompt i am getting this error

Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>cd\

C:\>svcutil /language:cs /out:proxy.cs /config:app.config /http://localhost:2544
/myservicewcf/Sasi.svc
'svcutil' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:proxy.cs /config:app.config /http://localhost:
2544/myservicewcf/sasi.svc
'svcutil.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>
```

can u help me please

Comment: Search for svcutil.exe on your machine. Then either do a CD "path" first and then execute your command or provide the full path "path"\svcutil.exe on the command line in your current command. Usually the default location is  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin

Comment: ya i go throught the c:\progaram file but i didn't find any thing in bin Mr.InSane

Answer (score 2):

Instead of starting a normal 'cmd' prompt, start 'Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt' in your visual studio start menu items

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin i didn't find any thing in bin folder

Comment: Which version of VS 2008 are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Use below statement to generate.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>svcutil.exe /t:code /language:cs "here your svc url" /out:urservice.cs /config:urservice.config
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the path value does not have the path value where the svcutil is available. Find the path from your system where the utility is available and use `setpath` command or add the path value to environment variable Path.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to mention the whole thing just the address of the endpoint would do the trick, like this.

```
  svcutil.exe http://'localhost':8080/MyService_endpoint
```

remove ' from commmand